# How to make sure the Print statement is executed only when the characters are distinct?

Tags: java, string

So, I'm writing a program for String compression. if the input is `aabbccc`, the output should be `a2b2c3`.

But in my program, my output is `a2a2b2b2c3c3c3`. That is because my Print statement is in a for loop. Which isn't supposed to be there.

How can I execute the print statement only when two characters in the String are not equal? so that I get the right output?

I've tried other ways of doing the String Compression program, but this way using Collections seems the easiest to me.

```
public class Compress {

   static int i;
   static int freq;

public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.println("Enter a String");
  Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
  String  str=sc.nextLine();
   List<Character> arrlist = new ArrayList<Character>();
   for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
       arrlist.add(str.charAt(i));
   }
   for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
       freq = Collections.frequency(arrlist, str.charAt(i));
           System.out.print(str.charAt(i)+""+freq);
   }
 }
}
```

**Desired result**

```
Input: aabbccc
Output: a2b2c3
```

**What I'm getting**

```
Input: aabbccc
Output: a2a2b2b2c3c3c3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code, there is no need to have 2 nested loops to do the compression. One loop passing through the input string is more than enough.

```
class Compress {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println("Compressed Input: " + compressInput(inputString));
  }

  private static String compressInput(String str) {
    if(str.isEmpty())
        return "";
    if(str.length() == 1)
        return str + "1";

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int cmpt = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if(str.charAt(i - 1) == str.charAt(i))
          cmpt++;
      else {
          result.append(str.charAt(i-1));
          result.append(cmpt);
          cmpt=1;
      }
    } 
    result.append(str.charAt(str.length()-1));
    result.append(cmpt);
    return result.toString();
  }

}
```

**Example of output**:

```
Enter a string: aaabbbbccddddeeeefg
Compressed Input: a3b4c2d4e4f1g1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.frequency` does give you the count as you can see in your output, but the problem here is that you need to group by each *character* in the String.

Make use of a Map:

```
Map<Character, Long> countMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
    countMap.merge(Character.valueOf(inputString.charAt(i)), 1L, (k, v) -> k + v);
}

countMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.print(k + "" + v));
```

Comment: *You can also use the same logic after using `Collections.frequency(arrlist, str.charAt(i))`*

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it in a similar manner as below. I have made use of a map wherein the key is the character and the value is the frequency of occurrence.

```
public class Compress {

    static int i;
    static int freq;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Enter a String");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        List<Character> arrlist = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            arrlist.add(str.charAt(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            freq = Collections.frequency(arrlist, str.charAt(i));
            hmap.put(str.charAt(i), freq);
        }

        for (Character c : hmap.keySet()) {
            System.out.print(c + "" + hmap.get(c));
        }
    }
}
```